# Jordan canonical forms of rank-one idempotents

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are rank-one idempotents in $B(V)$. They are similar. In fact, they have the same Jordan canonical form. Why? ( $V$ is a vector space over a field)

Comment: You may want to clarify your notations (what is $B(V)$?) to make it easier for others to understand what you ask.

Comment: The $B(V)$ is the algebra of all linear transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Such an indempotent $P$ with $P^2=P$ is called a [projection matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29); its minimal polynomial is $t^2-t$, which splits into distinct linear factors. Thus there exists a basis in which $P$ has the form
$$
    P = I_r\oplus 0_{n-r} 
$$
This is its Jordan canonical form, or course. The number $r$ equals the rank of $P$, so that $r=1$ in your case. Hence $A$ and $B$ have the same Jordan form.